Project and Module structure for C++ Modules
I usually use the pitchfork directory layout:
project/
├─ src/
├─ include/

where src/ and /include are mirrored (depending on which headers need to be public):
project/
├─ include/
│  ├─ common/
│  │  ├─ language.h
│  │  ├─ settings.h
├─ src/
│  ├─ common/
│  │  ├─ settings.cpp
│  │  ├─ error.h
│  │  ├─ file.h
│  │  ├─ language.cpp
│  ├─ flow/
│  │  ├─ flow.cpp
│  │  ├─ flow.h
│  ├─ main.cpp


include is public and exposed when deploying the project, while src is not.
The Project only has include/ and src/ as include dirs (I specify #include "common/language.h" for example)
I am in the transitioning from headers to modules;
What I am currently trying to grasp is the separation of public and private and how that should be reflected by the directory.
One could say that in the example above, one module would be project.common.
However, how should this be done, since part of it is public and non-public.
With headers, I just include the headers that I need (I have no big commons.h file).
With modules this does not seem to be that easy, If I want to have a project.common module that is both consumed by external applications as well as consumed by the project itself.
Is there agreed-upon convention or best practices to make a sleek module based project?
Edit:
With "private" here I mean project internal usage.
For example with the hypothetical module project.common,
for the consumption of project itself it would export error and file - project private headers,
while it should expose only language and settings to external applications.

You do know that someone can change the private to public in the header without recompiling and be able to access the private data in the code.

with "private" i mean project-internal usage.

I'd say it's much too early for there to be best practices. However, you could split the exported symbols into a different file, if you like. You say "should it be done" since some is private and not, but that is the point of export: not everything in a module should be public. And for project level public, look into module partitions.

"part of it is public and non-public" so how about extracting the public interface from internal details in a separate module, privately depending on internal details

I guess it depends on what you want to distribute, but let's consider you want to distribute the minimum to use the compiled version of your library.
Prior to modules, a source file (.cpp) was compiled into an object file (.o). But to be usable by another source file, it had to know the "interface" of what is available in the compiled object file. Thus you had to also provide a public header file (.h). (And of course instead of distributing many .o, we usually link them into a single .lib, but that's not relevant for the explanation.)
Now, a module interface file (.cppm) will produce 2 files: the precompiled module interface (named IFC, BMI, CMI, etc. depending on the compiler, with different extensions) and the compiled object file (.o).
Other modules and source files that want to use it doesn't need a public header anymore, they need the precompiled module interface file instead.
So in your example, if you convert all source files into modules, and you end up with no public header, it's just easier as all your source files are now in /src and you can get rid of the /include directory.
(Unless you still have some headers with macros to distribute.)
If you want to distribute all the source files, it's the same. Because anyway when you import a module, it doesn't rely on a path to include, so you don't need to have a specific folder to add to your include dirs. Note it also allows to easily move files / reorganize your whole directory tree without having to change a single line of code.
Finally, also note that distributing the public headers is often used as your basic api documentation. With modules, you still can separate the module interface (.cppm) and module implementation (.cpp) into separate files, and I guess you could also distribute the module interface in a public folder instead of distributing the precompiled module interface. I don't know if we already have good practices about which solution is better (or in which case one is better than the other).
